# Spring MVC page to page navigation not working

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have two pages: home.jsp, and stylechoosertable.jsp.  home.jsp has a simple link going to stylechoosertable.jsp.  Both are in src - main - webapp - views.  Starting the app runs fine, loading home.jsp is fine.  However, when I click the link, it goes to a 404 Not Found page.

Here is HomeController.java

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.");      
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Here is CSSTableController.java

```
@Controller
public class CSSTableController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CSSTableController.class);
    private final CSSService cssService;

    @Autowired
    public CSSTableController(CSSService cssService) {
        this.cssService = cssService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/stylechoosertable.jsp", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<StyleChooser> get() {
        return cssService.getAllStyleChoosers();
    }

}
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
```

web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

A couple of things I've noticed:

1. Only local:8080/myspringmvc/ brings up the home page.  local:8080/myspringmvc/home.jsp brings up the same 404 error, which I don't get.
2. On start, I can see it doing the Request/Handler mappings properly:

INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/stylechoosertable.jsp],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.util.List com.css.genapp.CSSTableController.get()

INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.css.genapp.HomeController.home(org.springframework.ui.Model)

1. It doesn't throw any org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound errors when I go to home.jsp or stylechoosertable.jsp, so I know the mapping is there.

I can't figure out why it doesn't "hit" my stylechoosertable.jsp.  Any ideas?

Comment: please post your `servlet-context.xml` as well.

Comment: posted servlet-context.xml and web.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I don't think I am able to get your question properly, still if you want to have simple navigation function from home.jsp, i.e on click of the link, it should go to stylechoosertable.jsp, then a definite solution would be just have a link like

```
<a href="stylechoosertable">SomeName</a>
```

Now simply map this in controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/stylechoosertable")
public String goToSCT() {
    return "stylechoosertable";
}
```

And if there is any stylechoosertable.jsp available in /WEB-INF/views/, it will simply get called.

Second Question the reason behind `local:8080/myspringmvc/` working, not `local:8080/myspringmvc/home.jsp` is basically lack of `RequestMapping` for `/home.jsp`, where as for the root URL i.e `/`, a mapping is there in `HomeController`

Comment: Hmm, so because I had ".jsp" on the link and the value in @RequestMapping, it doesn't work?

Comment: yes.. But it wasn't the sole cause, as `RequestMapping` return type is also not correct. It should return a `String` type where as you were returning `List<StyleChooser>`

Answer (score 2):

Most Servlet containers register a `Servlet` implementation to handle JSPs. They would look like

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jspServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.JspServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jspServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The `*.jsp` is known as an **extension mapping**. A Servlet container knows about this `Servlet` and the ones you've registered. The container doesn't know anything about your `@Controller` beans. That are relevant to Spring only.

When a Servlet container receives a request, it goes through an order specified in the [Servlet specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/) for matching a particular `Servlet` based on its mapping(s). Basically, it first checks for an exact match, then it tries to do path matching (patterns like `/something/*`), then it does **extension mapping**, and finally, if no matches were found, uses the default servlet, a servlet mapped to `/`. In this case, your `DispatcherServlet` (which runs the Spring MVC stack) is mapped to `/`, so it is the default servlet.

When you send your request to

```
local:8080/myspringmvc/home.jsp
```

the path satisfies the extension mapping of `*.jsp` and therefore the container uses the `JspServlet` to handle the request. This `JspServlet` tries to find an appropriate resource, but doesn't. Remember that JSPs inside `WEB-INF` are not accessible publicly/externally. It therefore returns a 404.

When you send your request to

```
local:8080/myspringmvc/
```

the default servlet is chosen because nothing else can match that path. The `DispatcherServlet` looks up its handlers and finds

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Model model) {
    logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.");      
    return "home";
}
```

By returning the view name `home` and because you've registered the appropriate `InternalResourceViewResolver`, Spring will do a `RequestDispatcher#forward(..)` to that JSP. That request will again be matched by the Servlet container, but this time, to the `JspServlet`. Because this is an internal call (and the path is right), the request will be completed.

Similarly, for `/stylechoosertable.jsp`, the `JspServlet` is chosen before your `DispatcherServlet` could do anything about it.

> It doesn't throw any `org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound`
>   errors when I go to home.jsp or stylechoosertable.jsp, so I know the
>   mapping is there.

The `DispatcherServlet` is never involved, so it doesn't have the chance to log anything.